# Sorting and nesting from flat array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping, reduce

Based on checkbox i check(used recoil for that) i got call from API with events List. I need to sort it with nesting because then i want to show it on my appilcation(names, with subnames etc, time etc). The thing is you can always show only 1 main sport(no need to showing names for tenis and football, only one). But i got problem with converting data to expected result

Call from API:

```
data: 
[
    {
        "eventId": 30169172,
        "remoteId": 35046955,
        "eventName": "Polanka - Ssk Bilovec",
        "eventStart": 1659279600000,
        "eventType": 1,
        "category3Id": 192,
        "category2Id": 138,
        "category1Id": 1,
        "category3Name": "Puchar",
        "category2Name": "Czechy",
        "category1Name": "Piłka nożna",
        "eventCodeId": null,
        "gamesCount": 18,
        "outcomesCount": null,
        "treatAsSport": 1,
        "category3AggregatedId": null,
        "eventGames": [
            {
                "gameId": 750475832,
                "gameName": "1X2",
                "gameType": 1,
                "gameCode": 0,
                "argument": 0,
                "combinationType": 1,
                "marketTypes": [],
                "gameLayout": 1,
                "eventLayout": 1,
             
            },
            {
                "gameId": 750511223,
                "gameName": "Podwójna szansa",
                "gameType": 4,
                "gameCode": 0,
                "argument": 0,
                "combinationType": 1,
                "marketTypes": [],
                "gameLayout": 3,
                "eventLayout": 14,
            
            },
            {
                "gameId": 750511224,
                "gameName": "Remis - nie ma zakładu (remis=zwrot)",
                "gameType": 93,
                "gameCode": 0,
                "argument": 0,
                "combinationType": 1,
                "marketTypes": [],
                "gameLayout": 2,
                "eventLayout": 7,
              
            },
            {
                "gameId": 750511234,
                "gameName": "Obie drużyny strzelą bramkę",
                "gameType": 98,
                "gameCode": 0,
                "argument": 0,
                "combinationType": 1,
                "marketTypes": [],
                "gameLayout": 2,
                "eventLayout": 6,
              
            }
        ],
        "cashoutEnabled": null,
        "participants": [
            {
                "localId": 196702,
                "remoteId": 390340,
                "name": "Polanka",
                "number": 1
            },
            {
                "localId": 235004,
                "remoteId": 426241,
                "name": "Ssk Bilovec",
                "number": 2
            }
        ],
        "tvChannelInfo": null,
        "result": null,
        "videoStream": null,
        "betsCounter": null,
        "sportId": null,
        "countryId": null,
        "leagueId": null,
        "sportName": null,
        "eventExtendedData": {
            "neutralGround": "-1",
            "remoteCategoryId": ""
        },
        "isOutright": null,
        "marketTypesOrder": null,
        "flashscoreLink": null,
        "betBuilderModel": null
    },
    {
        "eventId": 30169276,
        "remoteId": 34859787,
        "eventName": "Trutnov - Usti N Orlici",
        "eventStart": 1659279600000,
        "eventType": 1,
        "category3Id": 192,
        "category2Id": 138,
        "category1Id": 1,
        "category3Name": "Puchar",
        "category2Name": "Czechy",
        "category1Name": "Piłka nożna",
        "eventCodeId": null,
        "gamesCount": 19,
        "outcomesCount": null,
        "treatAsSport": 1,
        "category3AggregatedId": null,
        "eventGames": [
            {
                "gameId": 750479980,
                "gameName": "1X2",
                "gameType": 1,
                "gameCode": 0,
                "argument": 0,
                "combinationType": 1,
                "marketTypes": [],
                "gameLayout": 1,
                "eventLayout": 1,
             
            },
            {
                "gameId": 750501665,
                "gameName": "Podwójna szansa",
                "gameType": 4,
                "gameCode": 0,
                "argument": 0,
                "combinationType": 1,
                "marketTypes": [],
                "gameLayout": 3,
                "eventLayout": 14,
              
            },
            {
                "gameId": 750501663,
                "gameName": "Remis - nie ma zakładu (remis=zwrot)",
                "gameType": 93,
                "gameCode": 0,
                "argument": 0,
                "combinationType": 1,
                "marketTypes": [],
                "gameLayout": 2,
                "eventLayout": 7,
            },
            {
                "gameId": 750501668,
                "gameName": "Obie drużyny strzelą bramkę",
                "gameType": 98,
                "gameCode": 0,
                "argument": 0,
                "combinationType": 1,
                "marketTypes": [],
                "gameLayout": 2,
                "eventLayout": 6,
             
            }
        ],
        "cashoutEnabled": null,
        "participants": [
            {
                "localId": 83358,
                "remoteId": 43657,
                "name": "Trutnov",
                "number": 1
            },
            {
                "localId": 84918,
                "remoteId": 35252,
                "name": "Usti N Orlici",
                "number": 2
            }
        ],
        "tvChannelInfo": null,
        "result": null,
        "videoStream": null,
        "betsCounter": null,
        "sportId": null,
        "countryId": null,
        "leagueId": null,
        "sportName": null,
        "eventExtendedData": {
            "neutralGround": "-1",
            "remoteCategoryId": ""
        },
        "isOutright": null,
        "marketTypesOrder": null,
        "flashscoreLink": null,
        "betBuilderModel": null
    },
    {
        "eventId": 30169445,
        "remoteId": 34859607,
        "eventName": "TJ Sokol Lanzhot - FK Hodonin",
        "eventStart": 1659279600000,
        "eventType": 1,
        "category3Id": 192,
        "category2Id": 138,
        "category1Id": 1,
        "category3Name": "Puchar",
        "category2Name": "Czechy",
        "category1Name": "Piłka nożna",
        "eventCodeId": null,
        "gamesCount": 19,
        "outcomesCount": null,
        "treatAsSport": 1,
        "category3AggregatedId": null,
        "eventGames": [
            {
                "gameId": 750485133,
                "gameName": "1X2",
                "gameType": 1,
                "gameCode": 0,
                "argument": 0,
                "combinationType": 1,
                "marketTypes": [],
                "gameLayout": 1,
                "eventLayout": 1,
              
            },
            {
                "gameId": 750502968,
                "gameName": "Podwójna szansa",
                "gameType": 4,
                "gameCode": 0,
                "argument": 0,
                "combinationType": 1,
                "marketTypes": [],
                "gameLayout": 3,
                "eventLayout": 14,
            
            },
            {
                "gameId": 750502969,
                "gameName": "Remis - nie ma zakładu (remis=zwrot)",
                "gameType": 93,
                "gameCode": 0,
                "argument": 0,
                "combinationType": 1,
                "marketTypes": [],
                "gameLayout": 2,
                "eventLayout": 7,
             
            },
            {
                "gameId": 750502973,
                "gameName": "Obie drużyny strzelą bramkę",
                "gameType": 98,
                "gameCode": 0,
                "argument": 0,
                "combinationType": 1,
                "marketTypes": [],
                "gameLayout": 2,
                "eventLayout": 6,
            
            }
        ],
        "cashoutEnabled": null,
        "participants": [
            {
                "localId": 138671,
                "remoteId": 413745,
                "name": "TJ Sokol Lanzhot",
                "number": 1
            },
            {
                "localId": 32927,
                "remoteId": 53137,
                "name": "FK Hodonin",
                "number": 2
            }
        ],
        "tvChannelInfo": null,
        "result": null,
        "videoStream": null,
        "betsCounter": null,
        "sportId": null,
        "countryId": null,
        "leagueId": null,
        "sportName": null,
        "eventExtendedData": {
            "neutralGround": "-1",
            "remoteCategoryId": ""
        },
        "isOutright": null,
        "marketTypesOrder": null,
        "flashscoreLink": null,
        "betBuilderModel": null
    },
    {
        "eventId": 30181746,
        "remoteId": 35060577,
        "eventName": "Tj Tatran Bohunice - FK Apos Blansko",
        "eventStart": 1659454200000,
        "eventType": 1,
        "category3Id": 192,
        "category2Id": 138,
        "category1Id": 1,
        "category3Name": "Puchar",
        "category2Name": "Czechy",
        "category1Name": "Piłka nożna",
        "eventCodeId": null,
        "gamesCount": 1,
        "outcomesCount": null,
        "treatAsSport": 1,
        "category3AggregatedId": null,
        "eventGames": [
            {
                "gameId": 750896819,
                "gameName": "1X2",
                "gameType": 1,
                "gameCode": 0,
                "argument": 0,
                "combinationType": 1,
                "marketTypes": [],
                "gameLayout": 1,
                "eventLayout": 1,
              
            }
        ],
        "cashoutEnabled": null,
        "participants": [
            {
                "localId": 232463,
                "remoteId": 53129,
                "name": "Tj Tatran Bohunice",
                "number": 1
            },
            {
                "localId": 35065,
                "remoteId": 106331,
                "name": "FK Apos Blansko",
                "number": 2
            }
        ],
        "tvChannelInfo": null,
        "result": null,
        "videoStream": null,
        "betsCounter": null,
        "sportId": null,
        "countryId": null,
        "leagueId": null,
        "sportName": null,
        "eventExtendedData": {
            "neutralGround": "-1",
            "remoteCategoryId": ""
        },
        "isOutright": null,
        "marketTypesOrder": null,
        "flashscoreLink": null,
        "betBuilderModel": null
    },
    {
        "eventId": 29958729,
        "remoteId": 34280159,
        "eventName": "FK Varnsdorf - SFC Opawa",
        "eventStart": 1659279600000,
        "eventType": 1,
        "category3Id": 966,
        "category2Id": 138,
        "category1Id": 1,
        "category3Name": "2. Liga",
        "category2Name": "Czechy",
        "category1Name": "Piłka nożna",
        "eventCodeId": null,
        "gamesCount": 25,
        "outcomesCount": null,
        "treatAsSport": 1,
        "category3AggregatedId": null,
        "eventGames": [
            {
                "gameId": 743527938,
                "gameName": "1X2",
                "gameType": 1,
                "gameCode": 0,
                "argument": 0,
                "combinationType": 1,
                "marketTypes": [],
                "gameLayout": 1,
                "eventLayout": 1,
              
            },
            {
                "gameId": 743527937,
                "gameName": "Podwójna szansa",
                "gameType": 4,
                "gameCode": 0,
                "argument": 0,
                "combinationType": 1,
                "marketTypes": [],
                "gameLayout": 3,
                "eventLayout": 14,
             
            },
            {
                "gameId": 743527939,
                "gameName": "Remis - nie ma zakładu (remis=zwrot)",
                "gameType": 93,
                "gameCode": 0,
                "argument": 0,
                "combinationType": 1,
                "marketTypes": [],
                "gameLayout": 2,
                "eventLayout": 7,
             
            },
            {
                "gameId": 747215198,
                "gameName": "poniżej/powyżej 2.5 goli",
                "gameType": 8,
                "gameCode": 0,
                "argument": 2.5,
                "combinationType": 1,
                "marketTypes": [],
                "gameLayout": 2,
                "eventLayout": 6,
              
            },
            {
                "gameId": 747215302,
                "gameName": "Obie drużyny strzelą bramkę",
                "gameType": 98,
                "gameCode": 0,
                "argument": 0,
                "combinationType": 1,
                "marketTypes": [],
                "gameLayout": 2,
                "eventLayout": 6,
             
            }
        ],
        "cashoutEnabled": null,
        "participants": [
            {
                "localId": 9797,
                "remoteId": 34789,
                "name": "FK Varnsdorf",
                "number": 1
            },
            {
                "localId": 9798,
                "remoteId": 2215,
                "name": "SFC Opawa",
                "number": 2
            }
        ],
        "tvChannelInfo": null,
        "result": null,
        "videoStream": null,
        "betsCounter": null,
        "sportId": null,
        "countryId": null,
        "leagueId": null,
        "sportName": null,
        "eventExtendedData": {
            "neutralGround": "-1",
            "remoteCategoryId": ""
        },
        "isOutright": null,
        "marketTypesOrder": null,
        "flashscoreLink": null,
        "betBuilderModel": null
    },
    {
        "eventId": 30124046,
        "remoteId": 34393125,
        "eventName": "FC Dniepr Mogilev - FC Slavia Mozyr",
        "eventStart": 1659286800000,
        "eventType": 1,
        "category3Id": 514,
        "category2Id": 513,
        "category1Id": 1,
        "category3Name": "Puchar",
        "category2Name": "Białoruś",
        "category1Name": "Piłka nożna",
        "eventCodeId": null,
        "gamesCount": 25,
        "outcomesCount": null,
        "treatAsSport": 1,
        "category3AggregatedId": null,
        "eventGames": [
            {
                "gameId": 748950198,
                "gameName": "1X2",
                "gameType": 1,
                "gameCode": 0,
                "argument": 0,
                "combinationType": 1,
                "marketTypes": [],
                "gameLayout": 1,
                "eventLayout": 1,
             
            },
            {
                "gameId": 749258553,
                "gameName": "Podwójna szansa",
                "gameType": 4,
                "gameCode": 0,
                "argument": 0,
                "combinationType": 1,
                "marketTypes": [],
                "gameLayout": 3,
                "eventLayout": 14,
            
            },
            {
                "gameId": 749258574,
                "gameName": "Remis - nie ma zakładu (remis=zwrot)",
                "gameType": 93,
                "gameCode": 0,
                "argument": 0,
                "combinationType": 1,
                "marketTypes": [],
                "gameLayout": 2,
                "eventLayout": 7,
               
            },
            {
                "gameId": 749258571,
                "gameName": "poniżej/powyżej 2.5 goli",
                "gameType": 8,
                "gameCode": 0,
                "argument": 2.5,
                "combinationType": 1,
                "marketTypes": [],
                "gameLayout": 2,
                "eventLayout": 6,
              
            },
            {
                "gameId": 749258568,
                "gameName": "Obie drużyny strzelą bramkę",
                "gameType": 98,
                "gameCode": 0,
                "argument": 0,
                "combinationType": 1,
                "marketTypes": [],
                "gameLayout": 2,
                "eventLayout": 6,
               
            }
        ],
        "cashoutEnabled": null,
        "participants": [
            {
                "localId": 3872,
                "remoteId": 5231,
                "name": "FC Dniepr Mogilev",
                "number": 1
            },
            {
                "localId": 6314,
                "remoteId": 3358,
                "name": "FC Slavia Mozyr",
                "number": 2
            }
        ],
        "tvChannelInfo": null,
        "result": null,
        "videoStream": null,
        "betsCounter": null,
        "sportId": null,
        "countryId": null,
        "leagueId": null,
        "sportName": null,
        "eventExtendedData": {
            "neutralGround": "-1",
            "remoteCategoryId": ""
        },
        "isOutright": null,
        "marketTypesOrder": null,
        "flashscoreLink": null,
        "betBuilderModel": null
    }
]
```

I need to nest my data to look something like this:

```
[
{
 sportName: Football, 
 countries: 
       { 
         Italy: { leagueName: [Serie A: and here all events from serie A , Serie B: etc ]},
         Belgium: { leagueName: [First Division A: all events from First Division A ]
       }
}]
```

**It doesn't need to be exacly the same but looking for some concepts which can help to sort and nest it**

Now my code is looking like this:

```
const transform = () => {
  const sport = data[0].sportName
  const league = data.reduce(
          (array, element) => {
            array[element.countries] ??= []
            if (!array[element.countries].includes(element.leagueName)) {
              array[element.countries].push(element.leagueName)
            }

            return array
          },
          {}
        )

        return { sport, league }
      }

      return transform()
```

and giving:

```
{ sportName: Football, countries: { Belgium: ['First Division A'], Italy: [Serie B, Serie A]}}
```

Comment: Can you provide a valid JSON?

Comment: @ITgoldman yeye i was trying to short it because it's veeerry verryy long. Now should be ok

Answer (score 1):

If you provide one or two items for expected output I can refine this answer. For now, it's just object of object of object.

```js
var data = get_from_api();


var obj = data.reduce(function (agg, item)  {
  agg[item.sportName] ??= {}
  agg[item.sportName][item.country] ??= {}
  agg[item.sportName][item.country][item.leagueName] ??= []
  agg[item.sportName][item.country][item.leagueName].push(item)
   
  return agg;
}, {});

console.log(obj)


function get_from_api() {
  return [{
      sportNameId: 1,
      sportName: "Football",
      countryId: 118,
      country: "Italy",
      leagueId: 122,
      leagueName: "Serie A",
      eventGames: [],
      eventId: 29688791,
      eventName: "Sampdoria - Atalanta",
    },
    {
      sportNameId: 1,
      sportName: "Football",
      countryId: 118,
      country: "Italy",
      leagueId: 122,
      leagueName: "Serie A",
      eventGames: [],
      eventId: 29721942,
      eventName: "Torino - Lazio",
    },

    {
      sportNameId: 1,
      sportName: "Football",
      countryId: 118,
      country: "Italy",
      leagueId: 29560,
      leagueName: "Serie B",
      eventGames: [],
      eventId: 29409106,
      eventName: "US Palermo - Perugia"
    },
    {
      sportNameId: 1,
      sportName: "Football",
      countryId: 365,
      country: "Belgium",
      leagueId: 29492,
      leagueName: "First Division A",
      eventGames: [],
      eventId: 29688791,
      eventName: "KRC Genk - Standard Liege"
    }
  ]
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```